# VS2017 can't find git from command line in W7 Professional

Tags: git, path, visual-studio-2017

I have two VS2017 systems next to me.  One is on a W7 Home Premium x64.  The other is on a W7 Professional x64.  And both instances of VS2017 were installed from the same files at around the same time. (although I can't remember if they were installed with exactly the same options)

On the Home Premium system I can go to the Team Explorer tab, right click on a repository, select open command prompt and then use git from that command line.

On the Professional system, once I get to the command prompt I get the message:

> 'git' is not recognized as an external or internal command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Yet I have not had any indication from within VS2017 that there was anything wrong with any git operations.

On both machines I find Git at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team
>   Explorer\Git

But on the working machine there is no explicit path to this location.

What is going on with my non-working W7 Professional system?

---

**Forehead slap**

While there is nothing in the path pointing to the version of git being used by VS2017 for my W7 Home Premium, when I looked more closely at the path I realized that at some point in the past I had manually installed `Git for Windows` directly from [Git-Scm](https://git-scm.com/download/win), and that this was the version being referenced from with in the VS2017 command line window.

As such the real question should have been

> Why is Git working from the command line on my W7 Home Premium system
>   in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is going on with my non-working W7 Professional system?

Check the value of your current environment value PATH on both machine, which is used when Visual Studio is launched. Maybe one has that folder in it, or even is referencing another [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) installed elsewhere (as recommended in "[Get started with Git from the command line](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/share-your-code-in-git-cmdline)").

See if the [Visual Studio 2017 Git QuickStart](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart-vs2017) is working.

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no indication that Git is not working on the W7 Professional system from within VS2017.  I edit, I check in, I revert, I create branches, I push to a git server etc.  And I checked the `PATH` (before posting this question) and there is no obvious components on the working system that are missing from the non-working one.  However I will be having another, closer look.